# Save your fellow Jew: does that include suicide?

Tags: suicide

It says in the Torah that one must not stand by while your brother's blood is being shed. If another Jew is committing suicide, would one still be obligated to save him because of this mitzvah? If so, to what level? (Derabannan or Deoraytah)

Note: By all means, it is for sure pious to save someone from suicide. This question is just asking if one is obligated to do so because of this mitzvah.

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50323/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Minchas Chinuch* (Mitzva 237) writes that the prohibition of לא תעמוד על דם רעך does not apply to a case of deliberate suicide.

He proves this from a Gemara (Sanhedrin 73a), where the Gemara asks why it was necessary to explicitly prohibit לא תעמוד על דם רעך, if we could have reached this conclusion through a *[kal vechomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmudical_hermeneutics)* from *hashavas aveida* (the obligation to return lost items to save the owner from monetary loss) to *hashovas gufo* ('returning' a person's life).

From this question of the Gemara, the Minchas Chinuch concludes that the parameters of the obligations are the same, and therefore one can infer laws of לא תעמוד על דם רעך from the laws of השבת אבידה. Consequently, he rules that there would be no obligation to save a life by suicide, just like there is no obligation to return a lost item which the owner deliberately destroyed.

> ראה לכאורה דאם אחד מאבד עמצו לדעת ויכול אחד להצילו, אפשר דאינו מוזהר
> על הלאו, לא מיבעיא דעל העשה והשבותו לרבות אבידת גופו וודאי אינו מצווה,
> כי העשה דהשבת אבידה אינה נוהגת בממון באבידה מדעת כמבואר בשו"ע חו"מ סי'
> רס"א ס"ד, אלא אף על הלאו הזה אינו מוזהר, דמקשה הש"ס בסנהדרין שם למה לי
> הלאו על טובע בנהר הא מוהשבותו לו נפקא ליה לרבות אבידת גופו, הא יכול
> לומר דנפקא מיניה במאבד עצמו לדעת דאינו מצווה על אבידת גופו, כמו דאינו
> מצווה על אבידת ממונו מדעת, א"כ על כן כתבה התורה הלאו הזה, אלא על כרחך
> דגם בלאו הזה אינו מוזהר ומצווה, כן נראה לי ברור

However, R Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe YD 2:174:3) takes issue with this line of reasoning, explaining that the leniency that applies to a deliberate *aveida* would not apply to suicide, because one does not have the same ownership of ones' body that he has on ones' money:

> וכן אינו ראיה של כלום גם לחדוש המנ"ח לפטור להציל מאבד עצמו לדעת, דהא
> ל"ד כלל לאבדת ממון מדעת, שלהשליך לחוץ במקום הפקר שיאבד ממנו הוא דבר
> שרשאי אדם לעשות כן בשל עצמו ואין מחוייבין למנעו מרצונו ולהשיב, ואף אם
> ישליך למקום אבוד מן העולם שיש איסור בל תשחית, הרי עכ"פ לא שייך לחייב
> בשביל זה להשיב לו דוקא אלא היה שייך לחייב ליקח ממקום האבוד ולהניחו אף
> במקום הפקר, וזה הא לא חייבה תורה לאדם להציל דברים מהשחתה דהתורה אסרה
> רק להשחית בידים ולא להציל מהשחתה כשאין לחייבו מצד הפסד הבעלים, אבל
> לאבד נפש הא אינו רשאי אף נפש עצמו ולכן ודאי לא שייך שבשביל מה שהפקיר
> נפשו שאין לו הרשות לזה יפטרו אחרים מלהצילו, ואף בממון אם היה מציאות
> כה"ג שהיה עליו איסור להפקיר נמי היו מחוייבין להחזיר לו, שלכן אין צורך
> לקרא דלא תעמוד על דם רעך בשביל זה דאף מקרא והשבותו לו דהיינו אומרים
> שהוא רק כדין ממון נמי היינו יודעין שמחוייבין להציל גם מאבד עצמו לדעת.
> ונמצא שגם לסברת המנ"ח ליכא שום ראיה. ולכן ברור ופשוט שחייבין להצילו
> ואף לחלל שבת על הצלתו, ואמרו לי שכן מפורש בספרו של הגאון מהרי"ל דיסקין
> ובספר חלקת יואב בפשיטות דמחוייבין להציל גם בחלול שבת גם את מי שאיבד
> עצמו לדעת והוא ברור לדינא

See also:

- שו״ת מהר"ם מרוטענבערג סי' לט
- קבא דקשייתא קושיא א
- שו"ת מנחת יצחק ח"ה סימן ח
- שו"ת מהרי"ל דיסקין קונטרס אחרון סימן ה' ס"ק לד

Comment: But who said he's still called רעיך if he's trying to sin?