Saving a life when the other person is putting himself at risk
Shalom,
I was looking for some sources who could help answer a somewhat polemic questions: Is it still a commandment to save a person who purposely endangers himself because of an ilegal action. Should one rescue for example (not so many examples come to my mind) someone from a drug cartel after he wrong them? Should one rescue a boat of immigrants that wants to enter a country illegally?
Thanks

Why is legality relevant?

Duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/120454/759

@DoubleAA The answer might be, but the question isn't.

You "put yourself at risk" when you drive to work.  You may also have a high-risk job, like a high-voltage electrician. You might engage in dangerous hobbies, like free-style rock climbing or sky-diving. Or visit dangerous places on Earth. On the other hand, what does it mean "save" - should you try to prevent them from engaging in those activities or save them in a specific situation when their lives are in immediate danger?

A completely different aspect is your relation with the subject - why you? Imagine a guy in your shul who loves bike rampaging. What makes you obligated to "save him"? You see a boat of immigrants drowning on the TV or driving by the beach. Why you?

@shmosel So should the questions be merged anyway?

@AlBerko, thanks for your comments! I am still thinking why (i)legality may or not change the equation.

How does illegality influence Halachah? There's no notion of Gentile laws in Halachah (except for monetary conduct). One day skydiving is legal the other is not. In the USA texting while driving is legal, in Israel, it is not.
