# Can one volunteer to be put in a situation which will require breaking shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

I know that pikuach nefesh, saving a life, can push off [Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48736/can-i-choose-not-to-violate-shabbos-for-pikuach-nefesh) (which I understand to mean, can excuse breaking rules on Shabbat).  If I am one of a group of Jews who could do the life saving, should I volunteer to be the one who will have to break Shabbat or should I either let someone else volunteer (because my participation is not a sine qua non) or let the situation develop until I am the only choice?

And what if waiting for anyone else volunteer, or letting the situation develop might then preclude any life saving -- should I jump at the role before I am the only choice because the opportunity is inherently important, or not, because one should not put oneself in the situation which then has to be excused via invoking pikuach nefesh?

Comment: Isn't this what Hatzola members do on a regular basis?

Comment: There is a gemara yerushlami which says that the mitzvah is so great that you should yourself should do it and not ask anyone else to do it. Maybe this could help?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.328.2?lang=bi https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.328.12?lang=bi https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.328.13?lang=bi

Comment: @dov -- I don't know. Can they sign up for shifts, or is each assigned?

Comment: It seems there are many cases where one of a group must break Shabbat, but no individual need be that person.  Some doctor must be on call on Shabbat, some firefighter, some soldier, etc. I am not accustomed to those cases being decided in the moment but in advance of the actual emergency.

Comment: @Ze'evmissesMonica understood but I don't know HOW they are decided. If every firefighter HAS to take a shift over the weekend, is that different from someone who can step up and volunteer but otherwise would have no obligation? Should one try to be "first" to volunteer or wait until participation is required and it isn't a matter of choice?

Comment: It seems like it would depend on circumstances.  If everyone has to take a weekend day, can this fellow just take a Sunday? How much trouble would it be to arrange his schedule to not work on Shabbat? Given that amount, must he do it? Doctors entering residency and fellowship deal with "can I use a non-Shomer Shabbat residency".  Such programs exist, because some think they are required. Not every frum med student uses one.  That points towards an answer.

Comment: @Ze'evmissesMonica your statement "How much trouble would it be to arrange his schedule to not work on Shabbat?" gets to the heart of my question -- should he even be trying, or should he jump at the chance to save a life at the expense of shabbat?

Comment: Rambam Hilchot Shabbat 2:3 כשעושים דברים האלו אין עושין אותן לא ע"י נכרים ולא ע"י קטנים ולא ע"י עבדים ולא ע"י נשים כדי שלא תהא שבת קלה בעיניהם אלא על ידי גדולי ישראל וחכמיהם

Comment: @Alex I was about to write it as an answer.